# Why is custom recovery a prerequisite for flashing a custom ROM?

Tags: custom-roms, rom-flashing, recovery-mode

I have read in many guides that before flashing, we need to have a custom recovery like CWM installed. I am not able to understand why is this a prerequisite for flashing a custom ROM. Can I flash a ROM without custom recovery?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Stock recoveries usually check the update.zip file being flashed for a specific signature that is only known by device's manufacturer and/or carrier.  You cannot therefore flash custom ROMs on stock recoveries, hence the need for a custom recovery which bypasses said check.

Comment: Yet sometimes the signature can be kept intact or forged. In those cases the stock recovery will do fine. For example you can flash a new recovery using the stock recovery with a SGN n7000.

Answer (score 10):

Technically, it's not prerequisite, but convenience.

You can download an update **using your** handset and store it locally on the sdcard, then reboot manually into recovery. Or use Rom Manager to do all that in an app and enjoy backup/restore and OTA updating without the need for a computer.

Stock recoveries won't let you do all the fancy stuff that a custom recovery let's you do.

**Among them are:**

- backup/restore
- using adb in recovery mode
- **flashing custom .zip's** (that's what you'll need)
- format individual partitions
- wipe individual parts (Dalvik Cache, /Cache)

Some handset makers have their own means of low level access to flash. Fastboot then has not all needed commands built in.

- HTC/Google/others: fastboot
- Samsung: fastboot, proprietary ([Heimdall](https://github.com/Benjamin-Dobell/Heimdall/downloads) open source flash tool)
- Sony / SonyEricsson: fastboot, proprietary ([Flashtool](http://androxyde.github.com/Flashtool/) by Androxyde)
- ...

Comment: U said that it is just a convinience, but is there a possibility that the stock recovery will not allow the flashing of an update if it is not signed? In that case it is a necessicity rather than a convinience right?

Comment: Yes, stock recoveries won't allow that (often). You can use other means besides any recovery to flash images (Heimdall & Flashtool being 2 of them). So for Sony & Samsung you can bypass to use a recovery (theoretically)

Comment: why do you call odin fastboot?